# RESTful service and naming conventions

Tags: web-services, api, rest, asp.net-web-api2, restful-url

My entity is called *Item*.

```
POST     /api/items          create a new Item
PUT      /api/items/{id}     update an existing Item
GET      /api/items/{id}     get Item by id
```

However, I need to retrieve items in three different modes: *Nearest* (by *latitude*, *longitude* and *distance*), *Favorite* (marked by *isFavorite* flag) and *Personal* (inserted by user).

I though I could name the three URLs:

```
GET      /api/items/nearest?latitude=xxx&longitude=xxx&distance=xxx
GET      /api/items/favorite
GET      /api/items/personal
```

But as I read this could violate REST naming conventions. Should I use a type parameter (sort of an enumeration)? But that way user could call `GET      /api/items?type=favorite&latitude=xxx&longitude=xxx&distance=xxx` and that does not make sense.

One last question: Twitter API doesn't seem to adhere to REST naming conventions, with endpoints like `POST statuses/update` or `GET direct_messages/sent`. What do you think about that?

Answer (score 2):

REST is not a standard - it's a concept, so in fact you cannot brutally violate it.

But in your case I would recommend to add one more GET route

`GET      /api/items?type=favorite|personal|nearest&...`

and pass your "mode" as a get query and not mix it with `id`

Comment: That's what I suggested, but I don't like one could call /api/items?type=favorite&latitude=xxx&longitude=xxx&distance=xxx, because latitude, longitude and distance are not useful for favorite mode...

Comment: So your query parameters must not be mandatory. You can check lat, lang and distance only for the "nearest" request.

Comment: And even here you can made this parameters optional. If for example you can get user location from db record - sometimes it's quite useful - like if your user is logged in with phone app and also with browser he can block geolocation for website, but you can answer the request without geodata correctly, because you already have it's location from phone.

Answer (score 2):

REST does not have URI naming conventions.

The issue I see with supporting

```
GET /api/items/{id} 
GET /api/items/favorite
```

Is that it's confusing to clients, because sometimes the path segment after `/items` is an id which indicates an individual resource and sometimes it's a name which indicates a group resource.

The issue I see with supporting

```
GET /api/items?type=favorite&latitude=xxx&longitude=xxx&distance=xxx
```

is that, as you recognized, it's problematic to let clients make confusing calls where some query parameters may or may not be applied to the results.

It seems to me that the issue is really the nearest items, since that requires a set of query parameters that don't make sense in other contexts. One other option would be to use separate top-level endpoints.

```
GET /api/items/{id}?favorite=true&personal=false
GET /api/nearest-items/latitude=xxx&longitude=xxx&distance=xxx
    [optional ?favorite and ?personal query params]
```

Note that this will break horribly if you ever add some other selection criteria which also requires multiple query parameters.

EDIT -----

Hm. Another choice would be to mash the three optional nearest parameters into one.

```
GET /api/items?nearestTo=12.34,54.40,5&favorite=true
```

That's not very human-readable, but are humans really going to read your URIs?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why it would break horribly... Couldn't there be another top-level endpoint with multiple parameters?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes. The issue is if you want to find the `/nearest-items` for that other endpoint. If the new endpoint is, say `GET /api/funky-items?requiredParam=xxxx&otherRequiredParam=yyyy`, then clients can't ever find the nearest funky items - they have to pick. You can add query parameters to specify the nearest, but then you're right back where you started and should have just kept the single endpoint with optional query params.